# Php script won't display Polish characters correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to load html from a MySQL database and display it via my php script. But it won't display foreign characters correctly.

I've already changed php.ini to have the default charset as utf-8 and I've set my php header to:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And it still won't display the characters correctly. It's starting to really annoy me because I've tried every solution and none of them seem to be working.

Comment: In database the characters are shown as you want ?

Comment: What charset your table have?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set charset on mysql query

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I just needed to add:

```
utf8_decode($html);
```

to the end of my script... god damnit.

Comment: That's a terrible fix. `utf8_decode` does an encoding conversion. To keep your sanity, you never want to have to do any encoding conversion whatsoever. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).